# How to send model object in Html.RenderAction (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using MVC3 razor, and I'm trying to pass an object to a partial view, and it's not working.

This works fine without sending the object model to the partial view:

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "ViewName");
```

Trying this doesn't sent the model object, i'm getting nulls instead (the object has data, and the view expects it):'

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "ViewName", objectModel);
```

Is this even possible using RenderAction?

Thanks!

Edit: I found the error, there was an error with the controller's action that didn't pick up the sent object. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: could you provide the signature of the action you are calling?

Comment: why are you passing the viewname as a parameter? you should be passing the action and the controller instead

Comment: @Html.RenderAction("Index", "ViewName", new {objectParam1 = objectModel1, objectParam1 = objectModel2})

Answer (score 27, accepted):

say you want to pass `foo` as model, make it first

```
public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

now make an ActionResult

```
public ActionResult FooBar(Foo _foo){
    return PartialView(_foo);
}
```

call it

```
@Html.RenderAction("FooBar", "Controller", new { Name = "John", Age=20 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had an error that I overlooked in the Controller's Action signature. Fixed it and now it's getting the object.

Comment: Does this pass ModelState?

Comment: Thanks! But I had to surround Html.RenderAction call with curly braces to make it work. Otherwise, Razor says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'"

Answer (score 35):

You can actually pass an object to a controller method using Action. This can be done on any avaialble view, for instance I have one in a shared library that gets built to project bin folders that reference my shared project (properties - Copy if newer on the view file, in Visual Studio). It is done like so:

**Controller:**

```
public class GroovyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyTestView(MyModel m)
    {
        var viewPath = @"~\bin\CommonViews\MyTestView";
        return View(viewPath, m);
    }
}
```

**MVC page (using Razor syntax):**

```
@Html.Action("MyTestView", "Groovy", new { m = Model })
```

or using `RenderAction` method:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MyTestAction", "MyTestController", new { area = "area", m = Model }); }
```

Note: in the `@Html.Action()`, the `Model` object must be of type `MyModel` and that 3rd parameter must be set to the controller variable name, of which mine is `MyModel m`. The `m` is what you must assign to, so I do `m = Model`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for adding it a year after.

Answer (score 6):

Usually if I have a model already available it makes more sense to use `Html.Partial` than trying to render an action.

```
@Html.Partial("Foo", Model.FooModel)
```

Where `Foo.cshtml` is a view file (perhaps in your Shared folder) strongly typed with with `@model FooProject.Models.FooModel` or whatever your model is called. This can be as complex a model as you need it to be. Model is your page's main model into which you must set `FooModel` - or just omit this parameter if the `Foo` view uses the same model as the parent page.

`RenderAction` is generally better when you have just simple parameters, because you're just simulating a request to a regular action which has routing/query string parameters - and then dumping that response into your page. It works well if you need to put something in a Layout that isn't available in your page's model such as an element in a side bar.