# using ViewBag to pass a model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to sort my result page (which is in another view than the filtration page). I have faced this weird issue I do not understand why keeps happening to me.

All the codes provided in very short form, please ask me if you need any other parts of my code for more information.

My Index view(where user filters results):

```
@model IEnumerable<Cars.Models.CarSearch>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
    new
    {
        id = "CategoryFormID",
        data_modelListAction = @Url.Action("ModelList"),
        data_makeListAction = @Url.Action("MakeList"),
        data_editionListAction = @Url.Action("EditionList")
    }))
{
<label>Make</label>
<select id="MakeID" name="carMake">
    <option>All Makes</option>
</select>
}
```

My SearchResult view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Cars.Models.Car>

<a href="@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", new { sortOrder= "Make", filters = ViewBag.CurrentFilters})">Make</a>
```

My model:

```
public class Car
{
    public String Make { get; set; }      //is my table model
}

public class CarFilter {
    public String carMake { get; set; }
}

public class CarSearch {
    public CarFilter CarFilter { get; set; }
    public byte PageSize { get; set; }
    public short PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(String sortOrder, CarFilter filters)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentFilters = filters;

        return View();
    }
```

All I'm trying to do is to get carMake from Index post it to controller in CarFilter form (since in my code there are LOTS of fields in the form and I don't want to write them all down) and when user clicks on sort by Make it GET the SearchResult method and it's supposed to set `filters = ViewBag.CurrentFilters` which is the value user inputted from beginning.

Now the funny part is, when I replace `CarFilter filters` with `String carMake` and other places respectively. It works like a charm.

My question:

- Why?
- How can I do this with `CarFilter filters`?

UPDATE:

Problem is that `filters = ViewBag.CurrentFilters` in my SearchResult view does not work with the type `CarFilter`, because it keeps giving me NULL value when user clicked on the sort by Make.

Second UPDATE:

I tried changing `filters = ViewBag.CurrentFilters` with `CarFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilters`. Now `CarFilter filters` in my `SearchResult(...)`method in my controller is not and null object, but ALL the values of the objects in the model class is null (which shouldn't be). I mean the filters object exists but it seems like the values of CarFilter class in my model haven't been passed by `ViewBag.CurrentFilters` to the view.

Comment: They are passed. But try to look at the generated HTML..it doesn't contain the values of the `CarFilter` properties, I suppose

Comment: <a href="/Home/SearchResult?sortOrder=Make&filters=Cars.Models.CarFilter">...</a>
<p>Make</p>
</p>
</a>

You are right, it doesn't have the values of CarFilter, but how can I add them to it?

Comment: I'd love to know myself...actually you can check: remove `sortOrder` from your action method (for it to accept only one argument of type `CarFilter`)...and use `@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", ViewBag.CurrentFilters})` in `href`...it'll work as you want it....But how to achieve the same with anonymous objects, I don't know...probably you'd need to make your own model binding...in the end it's not very good approach...I think it would be better to pass some _id_ to a view and then restore the actual data by this id in the target action method...so your htmls would contain less info...

Comment: Yes you are right! I think I'll have to just simply add SortBy in my CarFilter model class and pass along with the filters. I also tried to pass just the CarSearch model from Index to SearchResult, but again the values of CarFilter was missing. So I guess that would be the only way out for now, until I find another way to do it. I'll post the answer here once I'm done editing. Thank again a lot! that helped very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you canged the name it worked because framework found property name and the bind it to what you have within action parameters doesnt work so nicely with objects. My advice is to stick with simple types

Here is similiar case:
[How to send model object in Html.RenderAction (MVC3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959425/how-to-send-model-object-in-html-renderaction-mvc3)

Its not a ViewBag problem thants how it works in general. Its the prime reason for using flatted models  :/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Adrian. Yes, simple types are very easy to work with but also noisy and very long and ugly. If I could pass this object without problem it would make 50 lines of code become 5 only literally. But again, thanks, in the link you provided, I think I'll be able to find some other ways to pass this object than ViewBag.

Comment: Its possible to also use java script to serialize fields in an object within javacript and send it via ajax like this: var formData = $(document.forms[0]).serializeArray();
            var searchModel = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
                searchModel[formData[i].name] = formData[i].value;
            }
            searchModel.idSzablonu = idSzablonu;
            searchModel.idAktu = aktId; but its for serializing a form and sending the searchmodel not for viewbags im afraid