# I cant using Html.RenderAction in .cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**FRONTEND**

```
@{
    <div>
        @Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikTipWidget", "Admin");
        @Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikDegerWidget", "Admin");
    </div>
}
```

**BACKEND**

```cs
public ActionResult UrunOzellikEkle()
{
    return View(Context.Baglanti.Urun.ToList());
}

public PartialViewResult UrunOzellikTipWidged(int? katID)
{
    if (katID != null)
    {
        var data = Context.Baglanti.OzellikTip
            .Where(x => x.KategoriID == katID)
            .ToList();
        return PartialView(data);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = Context.Baglanti.OzellikTip.ToList();
        return PartialView(data);
    }
}

public PartialViewResult UrunOzellikDegerWidget(int? tipID)
{
    if (tipID != null)
    {
        var data = Context.Baglanti.OzellikDeger
            .Where(x => x.OzellikTipID == tipID)
            .ToList();
        return PartialView(data);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = Context.Baglanti.OzellikDeger
            .ToList();
        return PartialView(data);
    }
}
```

> **ERROR CODE:Severity Code Description    Project File Line Suppression State Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
> **

Comment: From the limited info provided, is `KategoriID` and `OzellikTipID` nullable int? If not then try to change `== katID` into `== katID.Value` and `== tipID` into `== tipID.Value`. You may also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8959425/13742790

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the back door, no matter what action name I give at the front, it gives an error.

Comment: You have redunant `@` characters in the code block shown for the 'frontend'.  Remove the `@` characters from both `@Html.RenderAction(` statements because the ampersands are not needed -- those lines are already inside an ampersand block like this `@{ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Revise your code in **FRONTEND** to the following (remove the redundant ampersands from both `Html.RenderAction` statements).

```
<div>
      @{ Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikTipWidget", "Admin"); }
      @{ Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikDegerWidget", "Admin") };
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.RenderAction` renders the result and, instead of returns it as string, writes it directly to the response and returns `Void`. So you will have to use it inside a C# block, denoted as `@{ }`, and end it with a semicolon at the end, just like how you invoke/call a void function.

So your front-end needs to be changed to:

```
<div>
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikTipWidget", "Admin");
        Html.RenderAction("UrunOzellikDegerWidget", "Admin");
    }
</div>
```

The other's answer (removing the redundant ampersands) won't work because those 2 `RenderAction` are wrapped inside a `<div />`. If you remove the ampersand, they're treated as just regular HTML. It will output as:

[image]